# 2.5 Proposition of Chapter 9 of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from the 196th page of [do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry](https://library.lol/main/0A30B69FEAD8267DB0705B4F81764346). I don't know why red line is right.

On each $(t_i,t_{i+1})$, there is $\frac{D}{dt}\frac{dc}{dt}=0$. And since $c(t)$ is $C^1$, I know that $\frac{dc}{dt}$ is continuous on $[0,a]$. But seemly, they are not enough to  get  $\frac{D}{dt}\frac{dc}{dt}(t_i)=0$, since $\frac{D}{dt}\frac{dc}{dt}$  is similiar to the second derivative. $C^1$ don't imply that $\frac{D}{dt}\frac{dc}{dt}$ is continuous.

How to understand it?

**PS(2023-12-26):**  Thinking of two geodesics connected end to end as agreeing on the tangent vector at the point where they are connected. So they are actually a geodesic. Therefore, $\frac{D}{dt}\frac{dc}{dt}(t_i)=0$ which is needless now.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your doubt is about one of the last steps in the proof that, given a piecewise differentiable curve $c\colon[0,a]\to M$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, if $$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}s}(0)=0,\ \text{for any proper variation}\ f\ \text{of}\ c,\tag{$\ast$}$$ then $c$ is a geodesic of $(M,g)$.

As you also point out, as the first consequence of ($\ast$), the author obtains that, for each subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ where $c(t)$ is differentiable, $c(t)$ is a geodesic, i.e. $$\frac{D}{\mathrm{dt}}\frac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d}t}=0,\ \text{for}\ t\in[t_{i-1},t_i].\tag{1}$$

As the second consequence of ($\ast$), the author obtains that $c(t)$ is actually of class $C^1$ on $[0,a]$, i.e. $$\lim_{t\to t_i^-}\frac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d}t}(t)=\lim_{t\to t_i^+}\frac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d}t}(t),\ \text{for all}\ i=1,\ldots N,\tag{2}$$
where $(t_0,\ldots,t_{N+1})$ is the partition of $[0,a]$, with $t_0=0$ and $t_{N+1}=a$, such that $c(t)$ is differentiable on $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ for each $i=1,\ldots,N+1$.

Let us recall now that, in local coordinates $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, the geodesic equation ($1$)  becomes the second order ODE $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+\sum_{i,j}\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\mathrm{d}x_i}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}x_j}{\mathrm{d}t}=0,\ \text{with}\ k=1,\ldots,n.$$
Solving the latter for the second order derivatives, taking the limits as $t$ goes to $t_i$, and keeping in account (2), one obtains that $$\lim_{t\to t_i^-}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2}(t)=\lim_{t\to t_i^+}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2}(t),\ \text{for all}\ k=1,\ldots,n,\\ \text{and}\ i=1,\ldots N.$$
This shows that $c(t)$ is actually of class $C^2$ on $[0,a]$ and satisfies the geodesic equation on the entire interval $[0,a]$, i.e. $$\frac{D}{\mathrm{dt}}\frac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d}t}=0,\ \text{for}\ t\in[0,a].\tag{1.bis}$$

Comment: Thanks, reliable explanation.